# Rewrite just filename in any URL structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible with .htaccess to rewrite a filename that can be in any folder structure?

What I need here is a rewrite of the ending of the url, if filename.php exists, I would like to rewrite it to filename.js:

So, I believe something like this would work for the root of the site:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase  /
RewriteRule filename.js filenamejs.php$1 [L]
```

But I need to implement this for any url structure, if the files name equals `filename.js`, it should load up `filenamejs.php`.

How can I do this so that no matter what url is accessed, if `filename.js` is the last part of the url, it grabs the `filenamejs.php` file instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use match groups:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)filename\.js$ /$1filenamejs.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks a million, just what I was looking for!